# Oracle SQL: adding the same sequence number to the rows of a query

Tags: oracle, numbers, sequence, rows

I am sending to a downstream application events and I need in each event a sequence number, as a control number that I don't have gaps, I don't miss sending events. 
What I am trying to achieve is having a db sequence, to have assigned to the results of a query the same sequence number. I don't want to use a procedure, function, etc, only some SQL.

For example I need a query result like this:

```
col1row1  col2row1 seq1
col1row2  col2row2 seq1
col1row3  col2row3 seq1
col1row4  col2row4 seq1
```

The problems I found is that sequence have restrictions is queries or that I have different values for seq1.

I tried this:

```
SELECT t.*, ROWNUM, 
CASE ROWNUM
  WHEN 1 THEN MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL
  ELSE MY_SEQ.CURRVAL
END as event_seq
from my_table t
```

or

```
SELECT t.*, ROWNUM, decode(rownum, 1, MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, MY_SEQ.CURRVAL) from my_table t
```

and the sequence is defined:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

Comment: '... that I don't have gaps...', be aware that it's not possible to avoid gaps in sequences...

Comment: The reasons I need no gaps is that the downstream system that receive messages will see and understand there were some exceptional conditions. Other than this situation, by setting NOCACHE, I will get each time one number, there will be no caching and I sould not have gaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are within the same session, you just just fill MY_SEQ.CURRVAL by making a call from dual with MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL.

```
select my_seq.nextval from dual;
select my_seq.currval, t.* from my_table t;
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, but I wanted something similar with what you sent me, but in just one SQL call, not in two.